# Azure API Apps - SPA login with authentication

Tags: azure-api-apps

I've been searching high and low for an example of using an Azure API App with authentication with a javascript client.  Specifically I am interested in how something like an Angularjs app can authenticate with an Azure API app.

The closest I've got is this example http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-javascript-client/

but unfortunately this does not use authentication.

Given many users with be using SPA applications with Azure API Apps I would think there will be a lot of demand for this.

Does anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-dotnet-consume/#authenticated-call-from-a-windows-desktop-application shows how to authenticate for scenarios where we don't yet have an SDK.  You should be able to follow the same steps from a JavaScript client.  Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Mohit